# Using subsetted data in Reactable table

Tags: r, reactable

In reactable, you can make edits to named columns as follows:

```
    columns = list(
        Species = colDef(minWidth = 140),
        AnotherNamedColumn = colDef(align = "center")
)
```

The data I am using changes weekly, and so I can't use a named column. I need to subset from a df this:

```
    columns = list(
        df[1,2] = colDef(minWidth = 140),
        df[1,3] = colDef(align = "center")
)
```

But reactable doesn't like this. Does anyone know how I can get this to work and actually get reactable to evaluate the subset code so I can 'point' to the correct column without naming it?

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And your question/code should include every non-standard package you used, in this case `library(reactable)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right then one option to achieve your desired result would look like so:

1. Put your `colDef`s in a list
2. Set the names of the list according to column positions in your df
3. Pass the named list to the columns argument

```r
library(reactable)

df <- iris
columns <- list(colDef(minWidth = 140), colDef(align = "center"))
columns <- setNames(columns, names(df)[2:3])
reactable(df, columns = columns)
```

[image]